# Finding minimum of geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, geometric-series

For the given natural number $0<n\in\mathbb{N}$, define the function as follows:

$$f\left(r\right)=2\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{n+2}r^{i-n}+1$$

I want to find the minimum for that function in the domain $r\in\left(0,\infty\right)$, I type some parameters in demos and it seems that the minimum is equal to $$r=1.5$$

But I don't know how to prove it formally, and why it's not a function of $n$

Comment: It is a function of $n$. For example, what if $n=0$? Then the minimum will be at $r=-.5$.

Comment: I stated that n is natural number so it should be greater then 0

Comment: The naturals include zero, as a definition is common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating the geometric sum:
$$f(r)=2\cdot\frac{r^{-n}-r^3}{1-r}+1$$
Note that $f(1)=n+3$. This function is extremized when the function $g(r)=\frac{r^{-n}-r^3}{1-r}$ is extremized. Let's work with that instead. Differentiating and equating to zero:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}r}=\frac{r^{-1-n}\left(n(r-1)+r+r^{3+n}(2r-3)\right)}{(1-r)^2}=0$$
Simplify, using $r>0$ and $n>0$:
$$\implies n(r-1)+r+r^{3+n}(2r-3)=0$$
The minimum may be at the root of this equation. For example, for $n=3$, the minimum is at $r=1.1908$. Examining this interactive [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bvxwt7s3by) confirms this is true. Playing around with it also shows that the minimum is not $r=1.5$, and it really does depend on $n$.

I will note that, in the limit $n\to\infty$, $g(r)\to-\frac{r^3}{1-r}$ so our optimization condition becomes:
$$\frac{r^2(2r-3)}{(r-1)^2}=0$$
For $r>0$, this becomes $2r-3=0\Longleftrightarrow r=\frac{3}{2}$. So, in the limit $n\to\infty$, the sum is minimized at $r=\frac{3}{2}$.